# How to export the data to .txt readable by GNUplot

Tags: c, export, gnuplot

Yesterday I was too tired to post correct and specific question. So there it is:

```
if (t==2){
    printf ("abc\n");
    printf ("abc = "); scanf ("%f",&r);
    printf ("abc = "); scanf ("%d",&n);
    printf ("abc = "); scanf ("%d",&k);
    a=2*r;
    b=2*r;
    c=2*r;

    for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
        float x=(float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/a);
        float y=(float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/b);
        float z=(float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/c);

        if ((x-(r))*(x-(r))+(y-(r))*(y-(r))+(z-(r))*(z-(r))<=(r*r))
            m++;

            if ( i % k ==0 && i > 0 ){
                freopen ( "data.txt","w", stdout );
                printf("%s %s      %s \n","#","n","Vka");
                Vka = ( 2*r*2*r*2*r )*m/i;
                printf("% 6.2f % 6.2f \n",n,Vka);
                fclose (stdout);
            }

    }

    Vk=(2*r*2*r*2*r)*m/n;
    printf ("abc =%d\n", m);
    printf ("abc=%d\n", n);
    printf("abc =%f", Vk);

    }
```

Unfortunately program does not work as I want it to work. It should export the data to the file "data.txt", but the file still looks like this:

```
# n      Vka 
0.00   0.00
```

Morover the program finishes operation just after creating this file, while I want it to finish its operation on printing Vk in the terminal.

Comment: Don't reopen `stdout`! Open a new file instead, and print using `fprintf` instead. Also, when you open the file in the loop, you _overwrite_ the existing file. Also, you have spaces between the percent and format specification in one format string, which wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open the file before the loop
2. write to the file inside the loop using `fprintf`
3. close the file after the loop

There's no reason in this program to mess with `stdout` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use **open()** syscall to open the file `write.txt` and assign it to a fd, say `fdout`. Then use `dup2(fdout, 1)` for stdout.

You have 3 open pre-def file descriptors by default, in your OS, before you even reach `main`:
0 assigned to stdin,
1 to stdout,
2 to stderr.

From the manpage of `dup2`:

`dup2(int oldfd, int newfd)` makes `newfd` to be the copy of `oldfd`, closing `newfd` first if necessary.

The `dup2` call replaces `stdout` with your open file `write.txt`. So when you `printf` the data to `stdout`, it will be written to your files rather than to the pre-defined fd's setup by the OS.

This will not only get your job done, the opening and closing of stdout is not your headache anymore.